# Python: if not true function is not running as it should

Tags: python, if-statement

If the user doesn't type in multiplication, addition, ect, then a string should be printed. However, if one of these words is typed it still prints this string. I've just started with python; sorry that it's such a basic question!

```
print ("Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction or Division?")
type = str(input("Your choice:"))
if type != "multiplication" or "addition" or "subtraction" or "division":
    print("YOU DID NOT ENTER ONE OF THE ABOVE OPTIONS.\nTRY AGAIN!")
num1 = int(input("Enter your 1st number:"))
```

Comment: I’m no python programmer but, I thing you need to say type != “str” or type != “otherstr”

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I don't have a list of the words that should be accepted other than what I have posted here, in my code.

Comment: the function type() returns class type of the argument(object) passed as parameter, do not use it as a variable

Answer (score 2):

```
print ("Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction or Division?")
choice = input("Your choice:")
if choice.lower() not in ("multiplication", "addition", "subtraction", "division"):
    print("YOU DID NOT ENTER ONE OF THE ABOVE OPTIONS.\nTRY AGAIN!")
num1 = int(input("Enter your 1st number:"))
```

Also `type` is the built-in global name. By using this name you hide it.

Comment: What does .lower() do?

Comment: change your text to lowercase

Comment: @Francisca Rios Durkin https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower Don't forget to use Google

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on your if statement. When you are testing if a value is one of multiple options, you can use the `in` keyword like `"test" in ["hello", "test", "123"] == true`.

```py
print ("Multiplication, Addition, Subtraction or Division?")
type = str(input("Your choice:"))

if type not in ["multiplication", "addition", "subtraction", "division"]:
    print("YOU DID NOT ENTER ONE OF THE ABOVE OPTIONS.")
    print("TRY AGAIN!")
```